# To run a program compiled by Solaris (Sparc) on Linux (x86_64)

Tags: linux, solaris

There is wine to run Windows application on Linux, however is there any application to run a program compiled by Solaris (Sparc) on Linux (x86_64) ?

Comment: Off-topic at Stack Overflow. Maybe [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/).  Note that SPARC support is limited.

Answer (score 1):

Like wine does, I think it isn't possible.

You can look for a emulator. By example you can use qemu on your Linux, and emulate a sparc64 (niagara) running Solaris. https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/SPARC#Compatibility

I haven't tried to emulate a sparc machine on a Intel Linux server.